# Android изменить права доступа программно

Tags: android, java

Не получается на Android 4.2.2  поменять права доступа к файлу. (команда chmod 666 xxx).
Через консоль все меняется без проблем. Если дам права доступа через консоль то могу работать с файлом. но После перезагрузки требует права заново. При программном изменении (см. код ниже) не выполняет код (waitfor() возвращает >0) соответственно выбивает из приложения. В чем ошибка?

```
      if (!device.canRead() || !device.canWrite()) {
        try {
            // Missing read/write permission, trying to chmod the file 
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(true ? "su" : "sh");

            // Поток ввода
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

      //ttyO1 - идентификатор UART порта. В корректности адреса уверен в на 100%
            os.writeBytes("chmod 666 /dev/ttyO1");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            if ((process.waitFor() != 0) || !device.canRead()
                    || !device.canWrite()) {
                throw new SecurityException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SecurityException();
        }
    }
```

Пробовал уйму вариантов (вплоть до подключения Сишной библиотеки с функцией изменения прав доступа) ничего не помогло... Может возможно как то переконфигурировать загрузку самой ОС?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить возврат каретки после `chmod`:

```
os.writeBytes("chmod 666 /dev/ttyO1\r")
```

Comment: проблема не в том. было много вариантов... дело в том что тот же "ls -la>test.txt" работает, и записывает данные в файл, а команда "su" не работает... :\